# Installing Scikit-learn in pycharm on Mac

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pycharm

I have been able to get all other packages working in my PyCharm environment, however when I try to download either sklearn or scikit-learn I get an error. The error starts like this:

```
Collecting scikit-learn
Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f5/2c/5edf2488897cad4fb8c4ace86369833552615bf264460ae4ef6e1f258982/scikit-learn-0.19.1.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: scikit-learn
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for scikit-learn: started
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for scikit-learn: finished with status 'error'
  Complete output from command "/Users/.../PycharmProjects/StartingProject/VE Test/bin/python" -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/h0/0p8xxjc12kdgydxx7hpky_yc0000gn/T/pycharm-packaging/scikit-learn/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /private/var/folders/h0/0p8xxjc12kdgydxx7hpky_yc0000gn/T/pip-wheel-wy8d4dqc --python-tag cp37:
  Partial import of sklearn during the build process.
  blas_opt_info:
  blas_mkl_info:
  customize UnixCCompiler
    libraries mkl_rt not found in ['/Users/.../PycharmProjects/StartingProject/VE Test/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
    NOT AVAILABLE...
```

I have tried to use my command line to install it as well but I am not finding success with that either. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I would suggest installing Anaconda, which I believe comes with scikit and other data science tools

Comment: Thanks, I have tried that but I am trying to use tensorflow as well and I have not been able to get that properly working in anaconda but I have been able to in pycharm. Thus I am trying to get scikit installed but I can never get them both in at once.

Comment: Pycharm just points at a Conda environment, there is no installation "within Pycharm" that acts any differently from "conda install"

Answer (score 1):

To get scikit-learn/sklearn or any other packages to work in the pycharm, your python interpreter configured for pycharm must find those installed packges and other dependencies.

The specific error in given example might be due to absence of development tools such as `gcc` and `make`. Before installing the packages try to run following command (assuming it's ubuntu linux) -

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

For other distros see [here](https://www.garron.me/en/go2linux/gnu-gcc-development-tools-linux-fedora-arch-debian.html)

Also, you can also install packages that pycharm python interpreter can find from settings.

[image]